# Flutter WEB, Layout Templates. pop returning void but expects Bool

Tags: web, flutter, dart, navigation

I am trying to following along with this tutorial.
Progress is here:
https://github.com/vinceyoumans/flutweb001/tree/menu001

---

```
AssetNotFoundException: the_basics|lib/services/navigation_service.ddc.js
Error compiling dartdevc module:the_basics|lib/services/navigation_service.ddc.js

packages/the_basics/services/navigation_service.dart:12:38: Error: This expression has type 'void' and
can't be used.
    return navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
```

---

The code is in:
/lib/services/navigation_services.dart

---

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NavigationService {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  Future<dynamic> navigateTo(String routeName) {
    return navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(routeName);
  }

  bool goBack() {
    return navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
  }
}
```

---

The error I am getting:

A value of type 'void' can't be returned from method 'goBack' because it has a return type of 'bool'.dart(return_of_invalid_type)
from this line"

```
navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
```

So it appears a void is being returned when it expects a Bool.   any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

There's no implications when changing the return type. You can simply remove the return from

```
navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
```

and update your function to return void. I haven't seen it causing any problems in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can change the return type of the function to void or simply remove it.

```
goBack() {
    navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be necessary to add a null check (!) also:

```
  void goBack() {
     navigatorKey.currentState!.pop();
  }
```